# How to delete an attachment in an email in Evolution?

Tags: evolution, email, delete, imap, attachment

I would like to **delete attachments** from the email in the email client **Evolution** (at the moment 3.2.3, Ubuntu 12.04), so my the size of the IMAP-folders will not be bloated and can be reduced.

Comment: Ooops.. Thanks for pointing that out, I hadn't noticed it. Sorry for the link. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is **included** in evolution version 3.x without any additional installation. But it took me a while to find out how I can do it. At least **two ways** to do it:
1. **Right-click on the email** with the attachment in the email **list** of one of your folders and you will find the "**Remove Attachments**" in the context menu.
2. Left-click on the email with the attachment in the mail list to mark it and find in the **panel/main menu "Message" "Remove Attachments"**.

But unfortunately the most intuitive ways and where I looked for the command first does not work: Left-click context menu in the email itself and context menu of the attachment itself does not contain "remove attachments".

Comment: Or simply click on the "Message" menu, and chose "Remove Attachments" (at least for me with Evolution 3.4.2 it is there. So here you go with at least one "intuitive way" :)

Comment: Ooops -- OK, I didn't catch the word "panel menu" meant the "main menu". Sorry for that. But I agree with you they missed the most intuitive place: the attachment's drop down, where one can chose to "save as..." or "open with...". That would be the first place *I'd* look...

Comment: This feature is gone in version 3.18... The panel option is gray.